# jquery how to change dom properties on different webpages?

Tags: jquery, dom

i have 2 webpages: `xxx.com\index.php` and `xxx.com\test.php`

what i am trying to accomplish is when i click a button on `index.php` something to change on the `test.php`, maybe something like:

```
$('input#submit').click(function() {
$('.online_sent'). show();
});
```

where `input#submit` in on `index.php` and `.online_sent` in on `test.php`

i'm not using iframes, they are just 2 webpages, more exactly 2 sub-webpages on the same domain

Comment: Im assuming your using iframes?

Comment: Is test.php in a window that's opened from index.php?

Comment: You mean when both pages are opened in the browser? You can't do that directly. You could set some data on the server though and let the other page periodically check for changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

When a user clicks on the button you send something to node.js, then it'll send an update. On test.php have a listener that listen's for this button click and changes the page to correspond with the new state.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is not cool, I mean change a different file. I suggest you to put "variant part" into database. Then apply changes to database from index.php, detect changes from test.php